# Rest Api, Trying to fetch data from Rest Server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

Rest API is working fine with Postman and browser.
When is launching through jsp page or html page, It is hitting the Rest Method but response is coming "0".

Rest Client of JavaScript
Respose is coming "0" and response.data is coming Blank.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title></title>
        <script language="javascript">
        function getdetails() {
        var url = "http://localhost:9090/api/FGame/search1/";
        var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
        client.open("GET", url, true);
        client.send(null);
        if (client.status == 200)
        alert("The request succeeded!\n\nThe response representation was:\n\n" + client.responseText)
        else
        alert("The request did not succeed!\n\nThe response status was: " + client.status + " " + client.statusText + ".");
        alert(client.status);
        }
      </script>
      </head>
      <body>
       <h1>Call Employee Service </h1>
       <table>
       <tr>
           <td>Enter Employee ID :  </td>
           <td><input type="text" id="empno" size="10"/>  <input type="button" value="Get Details" onclick="getdetails()"/>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>Enter Name :  </td>
           <td><input type="text" readonly="true" id="empname" size="20"/> </td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
           <td>Employee Age : </td>
           <td><input type="text" readonly="true" id="age" size="10"/> </td>
       </tr>
       </table>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Rest API(Dropwizard)
This is Rest Api, I have used Dropwizard for this.

```
@GET
@Timed
@Path("search1")
public String sayHello()
{
    //final User value = dao.findByName(name.get());
    return "{\"id\": 238, \"content\": \"Hello, World!\"}";
}
```

//I have used with Angular also same error

```
<!doctype html>
    <html ng-app="demo">
    <head>
        <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/fGame.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div ng-controller="Hello">
        <p>The ID is {{greeting.id}}</p>
        <p>The content is {{greeting.content}}</p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have tried Angular also, But in this case Data is coming Black

```
angular.module('demo', [])
        .controller('Hello', function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('http://localhost:9090/api/FGame/search1').
            then(function(response) {
                alert($http.status);
                $scope.greeting = response.data;
            });
        });[![Postman Snapshot][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EeXH.png
```